# How to disable WinRAR warnings about unsaved modifications?

Tags: winrar

"Document.doc will be compressed only after closing the application using it. Modifications will be lost if you close WinRAR before that."

I just want to view the files, and find this annoying.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way to switch this off.

Go to Options/Settings/Viewer and enter `*.*` to the *Ignore modifications for…* field.

Answer (score 0):

A google search of this request turned up a few results. While WinRAR doesn't apparently have a way of turning these messages off, there are utilities that will do it for you.

See this thread for a few links. I was unable to open the most promising at work and so offer this only as a suggestion.

http://compgroups.net/comp.compression/Disabling-Winrar-Warnings-and-Errors